# How to disable annoying 'parenthesis completion'?

Tags: notepad++, code-completion

Whenever I type a (, [, or {, Notepad++ completes it with the corresponding closing bracket. I find this 'feature' annoying and would like to disable it. It doesn't seem to be listed in the Preferences dialog and a search of the online documentation didn't yield any useful result. 
Does anybody here know where the option for this is hidden? 
I'm currently using Notepad++ 5.0.3.

Comment: Most annoying aspect is that it's triggered when modifying existing code. This feature is useful only when writing new code, and only if you're on the last character of the new code.

Comment: @EricGrange You exaggerate the usefulness of the feature. In practice, it is useful only in the toilet.

Comment: Very annoying, but worse it stuffs up keystroke macros

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TextFX > TextFX Settings > Uncheck +Autoclose {([Brace

Comment: Actually in my case, the option was already unchecked. When I tried checking it, my brackets got closed twice, like so: when I typed ( npp filled in with )). Maybe some odd bug.
Now I've uninstalled and reinstalled npp, and the problem is gone. Still I'll mark this as answer for posterity's sake. :)

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov I haven't used N++ in a long time, but I believe TextFX is a plugin and you get a 'TextFX' menu if you install that. If you don't have that one installed, maybe it's the Preference mentioned in ganders' answer that's doing it in your case (or perhaps the *other* plugin that Norbert mentions that does the same thing!)

Answer (score 68):

From version 6.6.8 onward:

Go to Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion

In the second grouping called "Auto-Insert", check/un-check the appropriate auto completion/inserts.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's more probable it's turned on in the ConvertExt plugin : Plugins->ConvertExt->Options
Tab Notepad++:  uncheck brackets autocompletion

Answer (score 2):

Settings | Options | Autocompletion

[image: Screenshot of my (german) version..]

Comment: add description on english, please.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above helps (as in my case), there's also a plugin called Xbrackets Lite.

Plugins -> XBrackets Lite -> Uncheck Autocomplete brackets.

I seem to recall installing this because the other two (settings/auto-complete and TextFX .. AutoClose) did not work.

Notepad++ 7.3.3.